# Matlab figures - remove filling from gaussian distributions

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I am emulating a NAND Flash mlc and I am using hist() to display the results which are 4 gaussian distributions.

The problem is that I am trying to display 8 distributions at once one the same figure and they overlap. So, I want to find a way to remove the filling inside the gaussian distributions and only keep the outline. Is there a way to do this? I have found that maybe "basic fitting" option in Matlab can do this but it is "grey" and I cannot select it on this figure.

--

Well I tried adding a simple a picture which can explain everything but I could not due to my reputation.

I am working in FPGA(ZedBoard) in order to create the emulation but that has nothing to do with the question I am asking.

So, I get an input file with single-precision values out of ZedBoard, which then I insert in Matlab and get the figure I am talking about. 
I would not think that my code in Matlab could help in any way that is why I did not put it.

Although, I should have mentioned that the eight distributions have almost the exact same characteristics so they appear almost on the same place. This is why I am looking a way to display them properly.
These "hists" below have to appear on the same figure without overlapping on each other. Normally, when Matlab is displaying gaussian distributions with "hist" uses a blue filling which I want to remove and only leave the outlining of the distribution if possible. I hope I have given a better view of my problem with this added.

```
fid1 = fopen('soft_without.txt');   
A = textscan(fid1,'%s');
B = char(A{1});
fclose (fid1);
output = typecast(uint32(hex2dec(B)),'single');
hist(output,1000);

fid2 = fopen('soft_with.txt');   
A = textscan(fid2,'%s');
B = char(A{1});
fclose (fid2);
output1 = typecast(uint32(hex2dec(B)),'single');
hist(output1,1000);
```

Comment: This is all well and good, but where is the code showing what you've tried so far? Please edit your question and add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Jubobs - an MCVE isn't relevant here, the OP has described the problem.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth An MCVE speaks a thousand words.

Comment: @Jubobs: the OP used hist.  There's nothing else to know, AFAICS.

Comment: You can assign the result of a call to hist to a variable, and then plot that however you want.

Comment: You can use `hist` to actually extract out the histogram values, then plot out all 8 distributions manually by `plot` and just plot the points themselves. Call `counts = hist(...);` to retrieve the bin count per bin, then just plot all of them on the same figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first put all the data into one dataset, rather than having a bunch of different variables:

```
filenames = ls('*.txt');  % or whatever you do to make up your list of files
data = zeros(1000, 8);  %preallocate

% going to use first file to set location of bins so they're all the same
fid = fopen(filenames(1,:))
A = textscan(fid,'%s');  
B = char(A{1});
fclose(fid);
output = typecast(uint32(hex2dec(B)),'single');
[x, bins] = hist(output,1000);
data(:,1) = x;

% set rest to same bins

for n = 2:8
    fid = fopen(filenames(n,:))
    A = textscan(fid,'%s');  
    B = char(A{1});
    fclose(fid);
    output = typecast(uint32(hex2dec(B)),'single');
    x = hist(output,bins);
    data(:,n) = x;
end

bar(bins,data);
```

This will plot your eight sets as eight different (side by side) bars. Another route would be to plot the over the top of each other but set different edge colors and no face color (possibly also experiment with changing width).

```
colors = jet(8); % eight colors from the jet colormap
figure; hold on;
for n = 1:8
    bar(bins,data(:,n),'facecolor','none','edgecolor', colors(n,:));
end
```

Comment: I believe that your answer is on the right track but not exactly what I am looking for. Also I should have mentioned that each txt file displays 4 gaussians with hist ,so with 2 txt files I get all the 8. I have applied your method, the guassians have different colors but they overlap. What I need is to only have the "bell" of the gaussian distribution without the color inside so that they can appear properly. Something like this is exactly what I am trying to do http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg/2000px-Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg.png)

Comment: Then just use `plot`.

Comment: I tried plotting like you said but each file contains 997472 values, the time vector is :  x=-0.2:1:0.997471*10^(6); but the figure that shows up has nothing to do with gaussian distributions.

Comment: no, I mean plot the output of `hist`, rather than doing bars, if you don't want bar plots

Comment: Well was using hist like you said but I still don't have the result which I am showing on the picture above. I want a gaussian like that and hist produces gaussians with blue filling inside so when there are 8 they overlap. :/

Comment: I'm going to try once more and then give up.  1. **assign** the output of hist to a variable, like in the code above.  2. **plot** the contents of that variable, like in the code above but using `plot` not `bar`

Comment: Sorry for not understanding what you meant but I don't have much experience with matlab. I did it and it worked! THANKS A LOT!!!:D